# Question regarding the paper by Atiyah, Bott and Shapiro: alternative description of K-theory

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, vector-bundles, kt.k-theory-and-homology

In [Atiyah, Bott, and Shapiro - Clifford modules](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/abs.pdf) ([journal](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0040938364900035), [MSN](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=167985)), the authors discuss the alternative description of K-theory in terms of sequences of vector bundles. I would like to understand the details of this alternative description and I came across the following question while reading this paper:

> In the proof of Lemma 7.3 authors claim that (using the notation from the paper) if we take two monomorphic extensions $\sigma_{n+1}',\sigma_{n+1}''$ of $\sigma_{n+1}$ then $E_n' \cong E_n''$ where $E_n'$ and $E_n''$ are cokernels of $\sigma_{n+1}'$ and $\sigma_{n+1}''$. It is true that these two extensions are homotopic **rel** $Y$ (this follows from the previous lemma). How does it follow that $E_n' \cong E_n''$?

.

Answer (score 5):

The image of the homotopy defines a subbundle of the bundle $E_n\times I$ over $X\times I$. The quotient bundle restricts to $E'_n$ over $X\times 0$ and $E''_n$ over $X\times 1$ and, in general, if you have a vector bundle over $X\times I$ then the restrictions to the two ends are isomorphic.